# Can one node be a client for several action/service servers?

Tags: ros, action-client, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have one client which runs a state machine that coordinates between planner node, perception node, localization node and motion control node. I am using ROS action to communicate between state machine and planner node. I want to trigger motion control node when planner node sends a goal status as SUCCEED. Is it possible to use same client state machine node as client for other servers?
If possible is it the same also with ROS2 (crystal)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323414/can-one-node-be-a-client-for-several-action/service-servers?/) by [SkandaNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/40897/skandanr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-05-17**:
does the answer to [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/243145/one-action-client-to-many-action-servers/) help?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-20**:
Question answered? Please tick the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark the question as answered. It should turn green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Q&A @curi_ROS links should already give you an idea, but to make it explicit:

> Is it possible to use same client state machine node as client for other servers?

yes.

> If possible is it the same also with ROS2 (crystal)?

yes.

In both cases: action/service clients are "just variables" in your program. You can create a virtually unlimited (within reason) number of clients that way.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-17**:
Multiple servers in a single node is also supported btw.